# SimpleXML return array instead of string or INT

Tags: php, simplexml, file-get-contents

I have a problem with simpleXML in PHP. Myy problem is, that i get arrays instead of strings or ints.

Via file_get_contents im getting following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<data>
    <name>579</name>
    <price>46</price>
</data>
```

In im PHP im using this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( file_get_contents( $url ) );
print_r( $xml->price) // returns array( 0 => "46" ) instead of 46
```

Does somebody has an idea how i can get strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast it as a string (or an `int`, in this case):

```
$price = (string) $xml->price;
echo $price; // => string(2) "46"
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a idea why the arraynotation( $xml['price'] ) is not working?

Comment: @KevinTurner: It is **not** an array. It is a SimpleXMLElement object (a libxml resource, to be exact), as `var_dump($xml->price);` would tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `strval` to convert it from an `SimpleXMLElement` to a string. If you want to get the integer value instead, use `intval`.

Using `strval`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( file_get_contents( $url ) );
$price = strval ($xml->price);
```

or `intval`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( file_get_contents( $url ) );
$price = intval ($xml->price);
```